# WHM plugin for Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, whm

Hi I am looking for a plugin which will allow me to manage Asterisk from WHM.
If anyone would happen to know if there is a plugin I can install that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, there is no asterisk plugin for whm. you can install freepbx on the same server and manage asterisk though.